# Laravel: Pagination error when clicking category page

Tags: laravel

I'm successfully making pagination, but when I click a category I got an error message:

> BadMethodCallException Method
> **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::currentPage does not exist.**

This is my view:

```
Halaman: {{$gmproducts->currentPage()}}<br/>
Jumlah data: {{$gmproducts->total()}}<br/>
Data perhalaman: {{$gmproducts->perPage()}}<br/>
{{$gmproducts->links()}}
```

This is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Gmproducts;
use App\Gmcategories;

class GoldmartController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $gmproducts   = Gmproducts::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
        $gmcategories   = Gmcategories::all();

        return view('frontend.pages.goldmart', compact('gmproducts', 'gmcategories'));
    }

    public function readCategory($slug)
    {
        $category = Gmcategories::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        $gmcategories = Gmcategories::all();
        if($gmcategories)
        {
            $gmproducts = Gmproducts::where('category_id', $category->id)->get();
            return view('frontend.pages.goldmart', compact('gmproducts', 'category', 'gmcategories'));
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your readCategory function `$gmproducts` is not paginated:

```
public function readCategory($slug)
    {
        $category = Gmcategories::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        $gmcategories = Gmcategories::all();
        if($gmcategories)
        {
            $gmproducts = Gmproducts::where('category_id', $category->id)->paginate(10);
            return view('frontend.pages.goldmart', compact('gmproducts', 'category', 'gmcategories'));
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
```